# Filter according dynamic conditions that are dependent

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a dataframe that looks like:

```
+----+---------+---------+
|    |   Count |   Value |
|----+---------+---------|
|  0 |      10 |     0.5 |
|  1 |      17 |     0.9 |
|  2 |      56 |     0.6 |
|  3 |      25 |     0.7 |
|  4 |      80 |     0.7 |
|  5 |     190 |     0.6 |
|  6 |       3 |     0.8 |
|  7 |      60 |     0.5 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Now I want to filter. Smaller amounts of `Count` require a higher `Value` to get in focus.

The dependencies could look like: `dict({100:0.5, 50:0.6, 40:0.7, 20:0.75, 10:0.8})`
Examples:

- if `Count` is above `100`, `Value` requires only to be greater/equal `0.5`
- if `Count` is only `10` to `19`, `Value` need to be greather/equal `0.8`

I could filter it easily with:

```
df[((df["Count"]>=100) & (df["Value"]>=0.5)) |
   ((df["Count"]>=50) & (df["Value"]>=0.6)) |
   ((df["Count"]>=40) & (df["Value"]>=0.7)) |
   ((df["Count"]>=20) & (df["Value"]>=0.75)) |
   ((df["Count"]>=10) & (df["Value"]>=0.8))]

+----+---------+---------+
|    |   Count |   Value |
|----+---------+---------|
|  1 |      17 |     0.9 |
|  2 |      56 |     0.6 |
|  4 |      80 |     0.7 |
|  5 |     190 |     0.6 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

But want to change periodically the thresholds (also adding or removing threshold steps) without constantly changing the filter. How could I do this in pandas?

---

### MWE

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Count":[10,17,56,25,80,190,3,60],
    "Value":[0.5,0.9,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.6,0.8,0.5]
})

limits = dict({100:0.5, 50:0.6, 40:0.7, 20:0.75, 10:0.8})
```

---

### R equivalent

In `R` I could solve a similar question with following code (thanks to akrun). But I don't know how to adapt to pandas.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(33)

df = data.table(CPE=sample(1:500, 100), 
                PERC=runif(min = 0.1, max = 1, n=100))    
lst1 <- list(c(20, 0.95), c(50, 0.9), c(100,0.85), c(250,0.8))

df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(lst1, \(x) CPE > x[1] & PERC > x[2]))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to perform the comparison in linear time. If you have many groups performing multiple comparisons will become inefficient (O(n*m) complexity):

```
# sorted bins and matching labels
bins = sorted(limits)
# [10, 20, 40, 50, 100]
labels = [limits[x] for x in bins]
# [0.8, 0.75, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5]

# mapping threshold from bins 
s = pd.cut(df['Count'], bins=[0]+bins+[np.inf], labels=[np.inf]+labels, right=False).astype(float)

out = df[df['Value'].ge(s)]
```

Output:

```
   Count  Value
1     17    0.9
2     56    0.6
4     80    0.7
5    190    0.6
```

Intermediate `s`:

```
0    0.80
1    0.80
2    0.60
3    0.75
4    0.60
5    0.50
6     inf
7    0.60
Name: Count, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much mozway. I accepted this solution as it is about 5 times faster on the real-world data as Shubhams approach, nevertheless I like his solution too. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Lets simplify your code by using boolean reduction with `np.logical_or`. This is also very close to what your are trying to do in `R`

```
c = ['Count', 'Value']
df[np.logical_or.reduce([df[c].ge(t).all(1) for t in limits.items()])]
```

---

```
   Count  Value
1     17    0.9
2     56    0.6
4     80    0.7
5    190    0.6
```

Comment: Thank you for your great solution. I didn't know `logical_or`, so thanks for that :-) I just accepted mozways answer as it was on the real-world data about 5 times faster.